# 404 deploying spring boot to tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am able to deploy war file from Jenkins build to tomcat but I am getting 404 when accessing the application.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.group")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'


dependencies {
...
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: qa
---
spring:
  profiles: qa
server:
  context-path: /group-api
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The `context-path` property only applies to the embedded tomcat. If you deploy to an external tomcat, the context root is defined there. Most commonly the name of the .war file if copied directly into `webapps` or the name of the context file in `./conf/Catalina/localhost`.

Answer (score -5):

You could try to restart the program. I did and it worked for what I was using it for.